# javascript in MVC view doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with javascript, this is a little part of my MVC view page.

```
<body>
...
   <form>
       <div class="form-group, row">
          <div class="col-sm-2">
             <label class="control-label2" for="comparison">Compare:</label>
          </div>
       <div class="col-sm-2">
          <select class="form-control" id="comparison" name="comparison">
             @*<option></option>*@
             <option value="<="><=</option>
             <option value=">=">>=</option>
             <option value="<"><</option>
             <option value=">">></option>
             <option value="=" selected>=</option>
          </select>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-3">
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.comparison)
       </div>
   </div>
...
   </form>
</body>
```

After the page loads I need to modify selected option under some condition.
My problem is: if before body tag I insert a button with onClick clause that calls

```
function myFunc(){
       document.getElementById("comparison").value = "<";
}
```

everything works. If I insert the button and `myFunc` inside the form tag, nothing works.

I would like to automate the process with condition after page loading. Also I want to change background color of dropdown if other conditions are not satisfied.

Comment: What do you want by 'insert `btn` & `myFunc` inside form tag'? Are you want to trigger `myFunc` from certain form event? Please explain further what you need to do with example above.

Comment: I don't want insert `btn` & `myFunc` in form tag. I want, after loading page, automate selection of "default" value and set the background color of dropdown by condition.

Sorry, i badly explained myself

Comment: So your script does work, it's just that you don't know how to do it when the page finish loading?

Comment: I know how to start my script when the page finishes loading, i can use `$(document).ready` or `$(window).load`. But, when executing one of them, the script doesn't start at all. I need to call only this line `document.getElementById("comparison").value = "<";` after page loading.

Comment: Ok so "I know how to start my script ..."  but then also "the script doesn't start at all"...  Which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

When I installed jquery library with NuGet installer, Visual Studio included the wrong script string in _Layout.vbhtml.
It inserted `<script src="~/script/jquery-1.10.2.js">` instead of `<script src="~/script/jquery-3.2.1.js">`.

Answer (score 1):

Please use below events based on your scenario. Inside this events, you can change dropdown value based on condition.

When the page loads totally (dom, images, ...)

```
$(window).load(function(){
    // full load
});
```

or

```
$(document).load(function () {
 // code here
});
```

After DOM load (not wait for all images to loaded)

```
$(function(){
    // DOM Ready
});
```